# the django localhost server says template not found

Tags: python, django, django-views

I created a Django project named HelloWorld and created an app called Pages. I tried to make a template using HTML in the structure shown below . it does not work.
relevant screenshots:

[image: The directory structure]
[image: sttings.py(i have imported os before as Django 4 uses pathlib for that in settings.py)]
[image: views.py]
[image: urls.py]
[image: the terminal shows this error at runserver]
[image: the site shows this]

please help and let me know what is wrong.

Comment: please post code as text, not as picture -> avoids retyping the code in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. standard django structure would be

```
helloworld
   helloworld
   pages
      templates
          pages
             home.html
```

and view:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/home.html"
```

2. if you want to keep the template in the "global" folder then depending on BASE_DIR most certainle you need to move the folder "templates" one level up:

```
helloworld
   templates
   helloworld
   pages
```

You can simply print BASE_DIR in settings.py to be sure where it
points to:

settings.py

```
print(BASE_DIR)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Razenstein, I tried to use the structure for making a template in the global folder and it works perfectly.